# Custom ngModel flag doesn't digest immediately

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to extend `ngModel` so that I have `$empty` flag that works even when the validation is failing. We're using it to show a "clear text" button.

The model override works fine, but I'm noticing that the flag changes don't apply immediately. Calling `$digest` throws an "in progress" error.

```
myApp.directive('ngModel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var checkEmpty = function() {
            ngModel.$empty = (ngModel.$$rawModelValue === undefined || 
                ngModel.$$rawModelValue.length === 0);
        };
        checkEmpty();

        element.on('keyup', checkEmpty);
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxg7nnwm/2/

Comment: which flag doesn't apply immediately ?

Comment: ngModel.$empty. anything watching this value fails to update until the next cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just simply `$watch` for changes and set the variable:

```
scope.$watch(function(){
   return ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$viewValue);
},
function(v){
   ngModel.$empty = v;
})
```

**EDIT:**

Of course, this is inefficient as it registers a `$watch`.

As correctly pointed out in comments, `$viewChangeListeners` do not fire for invalid entry. Binding to element events is also bad, since `ng-model` should be DOM-agnostic.

The approach that could work is to register a `$parser` that runs first. This would work *in most cases* - but does not guarantee to work in all, since any other directive is free to register their own parsers (at any time) ahead of our parser and invalidate the value before our parser has a chance to run and re-set `$empty`.

```
priority: -100,
require: "ngModel",
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
  ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(v) {
    ngModel.$empty = isEmpty();
    return v;
  });

  // needed for first time
  var unwatch = scope.$watch(function(){
    return isEmpty();
  }, function(v){
    ngModel.$empty = v;
    unwatch();
  });

  function isEmpty(){
    return ngModel.$isEmpty(ngModel.$viewValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works and put me on the right path. I'm having an usual issue unrelated to this where my ngModel directive is never "linked". It works fine in the jsfiddle, any quick ideas what could cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use the keyup event? To avoid issues with digest timings you should hook into ngModel's pipeline by using [$viewChangeListeners](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) instead.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    var checkEmpty = function() {
        ngModel.$empty = (ngModel.$$rawModelValue === undefined || ngModel.$$rawModelValue.length === 0);
        console.log(ngModel.$empty);
    };
    checkEmpty();

    ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(checkEmpty);

    // element.on('keyup', checkEmpty);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwup0s9j/1/

Comment: I would prefer not to use keyup, but the viewchangelisteners aren't firing when I input invalid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found that `$timeout` works, it sets up my code in the next cycle:

```
element.on('keyup', function() {
     $timeout(checkEmpty);
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with mouse events (e.g. Right-click + Cut) and actually is a bad idea since it ties the otherwise DOM-agnostic `ngModel` to the underlying DOM element. I updated my answer since my original approach was inefficient due to an added $watch